# Changing datatype lead to change the result

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, type-conversion

I have such a query:

```
select RIGHT(REPLICATE('0',10)+CAST(Productid as VARCHAR(10)),10) as haha  
from [Production].[Product]
```

if I change `VARCHAR(10)` to `CHAR(10)` then results have the length of 3 instead of 10?

why?

Comment: `CHAR(10)` is right padded with space. Check this `SELECT DATALENGTH(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),'H')),DATALENGTH(CONVERT(CHAR(10),'H'))`

Comment: That means, in VARCHAR spaces would not be calculated, but in CHAR spaces would be counted

Comment: The spaces are not added in `VARCHAR` however if you add them manually like `'H   '` they will be considered when using `RIGHT`

Comment: Those many data-types aren't there just for decoration, obviously they have different properties, and indeed this can lead to different result when used in a query. Did you even try to find the difference between VARCHAR and CHAR , If you had, you would have understood right away why your result was different.

Comment: As a complete sidenote, from sql server 2012 and up, you can also use Format: `FORMAT(productid, REPLICATE('0',10))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you `CAST` your `Productid` with value say `123` using `CAST(Productid as VARCHAR(10))`, it's converted to variable character type which does not have padding of spaces at the end.

However If you use `CHAR(10)`, it will pad spaces at the end of `123` and you'll get `'123       '` with 7 spaces at the end

Hence you'll have a difference when using getting `RIGHT`

```
DECLARE @var INT = 123
SELECT RIGHT(REPLICATE('0',10)+CAST(@var as CHAR(10)),10),RIGHT(REPLICATE('0',10)+CAST(@var as VARCHAR(10)),10)
```

Difference:

```
123         0000000123
```

***Note***: `LEN` doesn't behave in similar fashion to `RIGHT` and doesn't take into consideration the trailing spaces when calculating length.

```
SELECT LEN(CAST(123 as CHAR(10))), LEN(CAST(123 as VARCHAR(10)))
```

Both result in length of 3.

```
3   3
```

Comment: @Kaja check `CAST(@var as CHAR(10)) + REPLICATE('0',10)` and `CAST(@var as varCHAR(10)) + REPLICATE('0',10)`